# adding user interface within images embedded to google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, uiimage

i am trying to embed a simple image into a google map, and did it successfully using OVERLAY.
But problem is the embedded image is having different components (eg, if image is a house, components are PARKING, SWIMMING POOL, etc) and need to add functions to each component onclick. is there any way to embed these type of images onto the GOOGLE MAP.

Comment: You might want to add more detail to your question; it's hard to figure exactly what you are trying to achieve. I'm not sure, but I think you may be talking placing [Custom Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) on your map.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into building a KML overlay. This will let you manage your data as a single overlay, but retain interactivity on all of your features. There are many tutorials online, but the basics are you build your overlay in Google Earth, host the kml file on a **public** web site, then add it to your map.

Just as a note, many of the kml tutorials are for the v2 API. They are still applicable except for the part regarding the final code to add the layer to the map - for that make sure you use a v3 tutorial.

KML on v3 Map Example: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

Actual KML File: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml